# Do the rng axioms enforce any hidden restrictions (except the existence of an absorbing element) on the multiplication operator?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

**Definition**. An operation $*$ on a set $R$ has an *absorbing element* iff there exists an element $0 \in R$ such that for all $x \in R$ it holds that $0*x=x*0=0$.

Thus, if $(R,+,*)$ is a [rng](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pseudo-ring), then $*$ has an absorbing element, namely the additive identity.

**Question 1.** Does assuming that $(R,+,*)$ is an rng imply any other statements about $*$, other than those implied by associativity together with the existence of an absorbing element?

We can also recast this proof-theoretic question into a model-theoretic question.

**Question 2.** Is it true that for all sets $R$ and all associative binary operations $*$ on $R$ such that $*$ has an absorbing element, there exists a binary operation $+$ on $R$ such that $(R,+,*)$ is an rng?

N.B. Let us not assume that the rng is commutative.

Comment: Suppose $|R| = n$, where $n$ can be infinity. Can't we just let the additive group of $R$ be the cyclic group $G$ of order $n$, with $0 = 1_G$?

Comment: @JoshuaCiappara, sure, but how to ensure distributivity?

Comment: Hmm... Yeah, that's the snag. I'm not sure which way to lean in terms of whether this is true, but it's probably illustrative to consider $R$ of small prime order, so the additive group is constrained to be cyclic, and see if you can imagine a $*$ which does not play nicely.

Answer (score 2):

Counter-example: $R = \{ 0,1,2,3,4 \}$ and $x*y = \text{lcm}(x,y) \,$ (mod 5). Then $0 * x = x * 0 = 0$ for all $x \in R.$ You can't put an abelian group structure on $R$ because the only candidate is the cyclic group of order 5, and it's easy to check that doesn't obey the distributive laws.

Comment: Forgive my ignorance, but how is $\mathrm{lcm}$ defined in the absence of a (meaningful) order on $R$?

Comment: Forgive $my$ ignorance in the following response, but I don't think we need to care. The set's finite, and small, so we can simply define $*$ for every $(x,y)$ to coincide with the number-theoretic interpretation. The result will be associative. In other words, defining $*$ in terms of the lcm and modular arithmetic can be viewed as an abbreviation for a multiplication table, if you're uncomfortable that there are hidden assumptions here.

Comment: Okay.... I'm trying to construct the table at the moment, how does one define $\mathrm{lcm}(0,y)$? Perhaps as $\mathrm{lcm}(5,y)$ modulo 5?

Comment: $\text{lcm}(0,y)$ is not an exception. $0$ is the *only* multiple of $0$ (and it is *a* multiple of $y$), therefore $0$ is the least common multiple.

Comment: Okay, gotcha. Now is it true that there are precisely four addition operations I need to check? Each of which make $R$ into a cyclic group of order 5.

Comment: No, it's just the one addition. You're probably asking whether you need to examine every possible choice of generator. The answer is no.

Comment: Hang on... I think there's 4! different addition operators on $R$ that make $R$ into a cyclic group of order 5. My reasoning: There's 4! ways of putting the elements of $R$ into a sequence whose first term is $0$, and for every such sequence, we can define a different addition operation.

Comment: What makes you say that only one notion of addition needs to be checked?

Comment: Oh sorry, I see what you're saying. I think some of those sequences would correspond to a different choice of generator for the same group though. e.g. (0,1,2,3,4) ~ (0,4,3,2,1).

Comment: But would this not permute the multiplication table of $*$?

Comment: Anyway, I have to go. I'll let you know if I have any thoughts. Perhaps a computer program could check all possible combinations.

Comment: I $think$ you're correct that it's not as simple to verify as I initially thought. I'm pretty sure $R = \{ 0,1,2 \}$ with the same $*$ works as a counter-example too. Might be easier to check.